# Why does xor'ing two ushort values not return a ushort?

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion, xor, ushort

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# XOR on two byte variables will not compile without a cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726920/c-sharp-xor-on-two-byte-variables-will-not-compile-without-a-cast)

Why do I get a compile error in this C# code?

```
void test()
{
   ushort a = 0;
   ushort b = 0;
   ushort c = a ^ b; //ERROR
}
```

*error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'ushort'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this: [C# XOR on two byte variables will not compile without a cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726920/c-sharp-xor-on-two-byte-variables-will-not-compile-without-a-cast)

Basically, with bit operators, any operand smaller than an int is automatically converted up to an int.

Comment: @dbattaglia - So you understand the reason for the downvote.  This easily could have been a comment.