# Converting from string to byte

Tags: c#, string, byte, xor

I have a string which is `40FA`. I would like to perform an XOR operation to it and return a byte which is `0xBA` in this case. However, I'm only able to get that `BA`  in string. When I convert `BA` to byte, I'm getting `186`.

```
string tmp = "40FA";
int uid_1 = Convert.ToInt32(tmp.Substring(0, 2), 16);
int uid_2 = Convert.ToInt32(tmp.Substring(2, 2), 16);

int test = uid_1 ^ uid_2 ;
string final = test.ToString("X");
byte byteresult = Byte.Parse(final , NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Comment: It seems that you should put `tmp.Substring(0, 2)` instead of `output.Substring(0, 2)`; and `tmp.Substring(2, 2)` instead of `output.Substring(2, 2)`

Comment: thanks for that. i've a big chunk of code and I edited it when I posted it here.

Comment: Well, `186 (decimal) == 0xBA == 0272 (Octal) == 10111010 (Binary)`; if you want represent byte as hexadecimal format it out as `byteresult.ToString("X2")`; your code *does work*: `0x40 ^ 0xFA == 0xBA == 186 (decimal)`

Comment: What exactly is your problem? is it the output?

Comment: I need it to be in hex byte but it is showing me decimal instead.

Comment: ok so you actually need it in a `string` format to display it somewhere ?=! ok that is something you should add to your question. Because otherwise you solved your problem already. Because you have your result in the line: `string final = test.ToString("X");`

Comment: actually i need this output to be inserted to a byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a little misunderstanding here. You actually already solved your problem. The computer does not care whether the number is decimal or hexadecimal or octadecimal or binary. These are just representations of a number. So only you care how it is to be displayed.

As DmitryBychenko already said:
0xBA is the same number as 186. It won't matter for your byte array if you want to store it there. It only matters for you as a user if you want to display it.

EDIT: you can test it by running this line of code:

```
Console.WriteLine((byteresult == Convert.ToInt32("BA", 16)).ToString());
```

Your code actually does what you want if I understood you correctly from your comments.

```
string tmp = "40FA";
int uid_1 = Convert.ToInt32(tmp.Substring(0, 2), 16);
int uid_2 = Convert.ToInt32(tmp.Substring(2, 2), 16);

int test = uid_1 ^ uid_2 ;
string final = test.ToString("X");

// here you actually have achieved what you wanted.
byte byteresult = Byte.Parse(final , NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

now you can use `byteresult` to store it in a `byte[]`, and this:

```
byte[] MyByteArray = new byte[4];
MyByteArray [0] = byteresult;
```

should execute without problems.

Comment: thanks so much for clearing this up for me. i've actually got the answer in my own code.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(somestring);

and for bytes to string

string something = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(toBytes);
```

Comment: @active92 you cannot print just the array to console. `Console.WriteLine` executes just the default `ToString()` method of the type and it prints you: `System.Byte[]`

Comment: @MongZhu yeah. you are right. i can see the output when i'm debugging

Answer (score 2):

Try to call that function, it will convert `string` to `bytes`

```
private byte[] String_To_Bytes2(string strInput)
{
    int numBytes = (strInput.Length) / 2;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[numBytes];

    for (int x = 0; x < numBytes; ++x)
    {
        bytes[x] = Convert.ToByte(strInput.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16);
    }
    return bytes;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string tmp = "40FA";
    int uid_1 = Convert.ToInt32(tmp.Substring(0, 2), 16);
    int uid_2 = Convert.ToInt32(tmp.Substring(2, 2), 16);
    int test = uid_1 ^ uid_2;
    string final = test.ToString("X");
    byte[] toBytes = String_To_Bytes2(final);

    Console.WriteLine(toBytes);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input seems to be hexadecimal value, so you need to parse two digits as one byte. Then XOR these two bytes.

The result is `186` in decimal or `BA` in hex. It's the same value, just another 
base.

```
string tmp = "40FA";
byte uid_1 = byte.Parse(tmp.Substring(0, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
byte uid_2 = byte.Parse(tmp.Substring(2, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
byte test = (byte)(uid_1 ^ uid_2); // = 186 (decimal) = BA (hexadecimal)
string result = test.ToString("X");
```

Comment: I'm getting error for this. Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. https://dotnetfiddle.net/OEFJvc

Comment: You're right, I added the cast that's needed. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2726920/314334